# What is the correct permission in /etc/fstab to mount NTFS?

Tags: arch-linux, fstab, ntfs

I have Windows and Arch Linux in dual with UEFI. I want to mount my another NTFS partition in Arch. I mounted the partition with `mount /dev/sda5  /mnt/Apps` command. Then added the output of `genfstab -U /mnt/Apps` in `/etc/fstab` file. The output is as follows:

```
UUID=01D158CC7C2A61A0 /mnt/Apps ntfs rw,nosuid,nodev,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0
```

But when I unmount and remount that partition all files and folders shows with root uid and gid and 0777 permission. I also tried with changing uid and gid to 1000 but same result. So, my question, what is the correct way to add NTFS partitions in fstab so that I can read & write all file and folder both with normal user (1000:1000) and root (0:0)?

Comment: You've said you've tried with `uid` and `gid` set to `1000` but in your fstab entry you have set `user_id` and `group_id` not `uid` and `gid`.  Which of these two did you try?

Comment: I tried with both. But the permission is 0777 always.

Comment: @Biswapriyo see https://askubuntu.com/a/11843/158442 - use `fmask` and `dmask` if you want to set permissions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As commented by [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/11843), I have added the `fmask` and `dmask` permissions in `/etc/fstab` and now it shows correct permissions. I have change that line as follows:

```
UUID=01D158CC7C2A61A0 /mnt/Apps ntfs rw,auto,user,fmask=133,dmask=022,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

This sets all files `0644` and directories `0755` permissions.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! I couldn't find the fmask and dmask permission settings anywhere.

Comment: Correct permission to mount NTFS depends on the files. 644 and 755 is fine but You can't  execute a program in a case there are os-executable program in the ntfs volume. 
sometimes 777 is the correct permission for NTFS. sometimes 644 and 755 is.
The problem is NTFS doesnt support storing file permission metadata for each individual file, so the linux has to set it for the whole volume instead